# click on date that falls within 7 last 7 days

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

This is my requirement I have a table with a long list of dates :
date 1
date 2
date 3
date 4
date 5
date 6 and so on

. dynamically check for today date
. check that the date falls within the last 5 days
if the date falls within the last 5 days click on one of the dates above

This is my code:

```
var dateObject = new Date();
var month = dateObject.getUTCMonth() + 1;
var day = dateObject.getUTCDate() - 6;
var year = dateObject.getUTCFullYear();

    DateWithinRange = year + "/" + month + "/" + day;
    console.log(DateWithinRange)

  if(DateWithinRange   falls within  dateObject){ //compare to today date 
 
      await page.$evalaute("dateButton" , element => element.click())
      console.log("date falls within the last week")
        }else{
        console.log("date not in range")
    }


}
```

I dont know if this is the correct way to do this , I appreciate any help , thanks

Comment: It is difficult to understand what the issue is from your example. Can you give the input that is being compared and what criteria it needs to fit within? I want to know what `date 1 date 2 date 3 date 4 date 5 date 6` look like and where they come from.